# Checking if dictionary contains the date and plan

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

So I am trying to create a function that checks whether or not the contents of a function is true:

```
def command_add(date, event, calendar):

    '''
    Add event_details to the list at calendar[date]
    Create date if it was not there

    :param date: A string  as "YYYY-MM-DD"
    :param event: A string describing the event
    :param calendar: The calendars database
    :return: a string indicating any errors, "" for no errors
    '''
>>> calendar == {'2015-10-20': ['Python']}
True
>>> command_add("2015-11-01", "Computer Science class", calendar)
''
```

How would I write such a function? The problem I'm having is how to make the string or how to see if the string for the date is in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses `strptime` to parse the date, if the parsing fails it is not a proper date string. Then it checks if the date is already in the calendar dict or not to see whether to append or add the first entry.

```
from datetime import datetime

def command_add(date, event, calendar):

    '''
    Add event_details to the list at calendar[date]
    Create date if it was not there

    :param date: A string  as "YYYY-MM-DD"
    :param event: A string describing the event
    :param calendar: The calendars database
    :return: a string indicating any errors, "" for no errors
    '''
    try:
        datetime.strptime('%Y-%m-%d', date):
    except ValueError:
        return 'Error parsing date'
    else:
        if date in calendar:
            calendar[date].append(event)
        else:
            calendar[date] = [event]

    return ''
```

Comment: Suggest you use `except ValueError:` — bare `except` clauses are generally a bad idea since they trap every possible exception often hiding other problems with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Look at: https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime

Give `strptime` the wanted format and if string is not formatted as you wanted you will get an exception

Comment: you can only calling `strftime` on a date object, not a string

Answer (score -1):

```
from datetime import datetime

def command_add(date, event, calendar):
    # Your Code

calendar = {'2015-10-20': ['Python']}
try:
    Date = "2015-11-01"
    date_object = datetime.strptime(Date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    command_add(Date, "Computer Science class", calendar)
except:
    print "Date Format is not correct"
```